# Which is the best TimeZone settings for php mysql site?

Tags: php, web-applications

i am running a site and i need to set the timezone. which is the most preferable time zone??
my server is in GoDaddy.com. So any one help me to set the time zone via php.

Comment: i have been battleing this one for a few years, I can never find a solid best method

Answer (score 1):

See [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

As for the time zone: That depends on the nature of your site, I would say.

- You could have the user choose their time zone - nice e.g. for a personalized web app.
- You could set it to the server's time zone - if you don't care
- You could set it to the time zone where your business or user community is located - makes most sense with business sites and localized communities
- You could set it to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC), as Stack Overflow does. Makes probably the most sense when operating for a global audience, so that things don't get up in inter-user communication ("but in your comment at 2:21 you said...")

Comment: is mysql now() is okey for non personalised websites??

Comment: What do you mean by "okay"? You may want to add more information about what you are trying to do.