# PHP ini date.timezone? Server or client location time zone?

Tags: datetime, timezone, php

I know this might sound a silly question, but I did not find in PHP documentation somewhere were they state loud and clear this one.

I have got a web application.

**Users of my web appliations are in Europe**, but the **server running the web appliation is in US**.

How should I set the date.timezone php ini directive???

I suppose to where the server is located so if it's in New York: date.timezone = "America/New_York"

But am I right?

Comment: Not a silly question but has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852223/mysql-keep-server-timezone-or-user-timezone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981387/which-is-the-best-timezone-settings-for-php-mysql-site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346770/dealing-with-timezones-in-php

Comment: Setting the timezone to New York simply because the server is there seems to me (sorta) like keeping a watch set at Shanghai time just because it was made there.

Comment: @Pekka, thanks! After reading the last one you suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346770/dealing-with-timezones-in-php I undertstood something. I thought date.timezone could break the application or something between PHP and MySQL if not set properly. But I finally understood it can be set to what I want. So I think to follow the suggestion given in the last link, I set the time.zone to GMT 0 and when need to display dates/times I use client side scripting to convert dates/times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I read here around on SO the answers is:

1. set PHP **date.timezone ini directive
   to "UTC" (i.e. 0)**
2. let PHP print in pages the date time (UTC) as a simple Unix time stamp (a number)
3. let Javacscript transform the UTC Unix time stamp in client time by simply doing:

   new Date(<?php echo DATE_TIME_SERVER_UTC; ?> * 1000);

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's better to set server's local timezone or UTC and change user timezone in script using http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
You can set timezone to Europe/sth or compute it for each client using GeoIP or JavaScript (it should be possible)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php and [How can I easily convert dates from UTC via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952975/how-can-i-easily-convert-dates-from-utc-via-php)